# Using bootstrap scrollspy for a div with collapse, to an affixed sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code as the layout of the page. The span9 div cotains sections that should apply the scrollspy. Each section is a set of collapsible divs that contains the actual content. The span3 div is the affixed sidebar and must highlight the correct item using the scrollspy.

```
<div class="span3 module-sidebar">
    <ul id="sidebar" data-spy="affix"  data-offset="250" data-offset-bottom="0" class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
        <li>
            <a href="#module1"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Module1 Name</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="span9" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidebar">
    <section id="module1">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Module1 Name</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="bs-docs-example">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#function1">Function1 Name</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="function1" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <h3>Topic1 Name</h3>
                        <p>Topic1 Desc</p>                              
                            <h4>SubTopic1 Name</h4>
                            <p>SubTopic1 Desc</p>                                   
                                <h4><img src="../assets/img/manuals/module1/function1/step1.png"/></h4>
                                <p>Step1 Desc</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i collapse the div to show the content, the scrollspy won't recognize the newly occupied space by that collapsible div. and thus highlights the next items in the sidebar when I scroll through the content of that collapsible div.

What i want is for the scrollspy to 'see' the space when the collapsible div is expanded. Any help would really be appreciated. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_kenneth/2gpKf/17/) for the fiddle.

Comment: Can you create a test case?

Comment: What test case? How can i do that?

Comment: Test case in a working demo of your problem. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/pen/ for this. This way people can see your problem live and try various solutions on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `.scrollspy('refresh')` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.accordion').on('shown hidden', function () {
        $('body').scrollspy('refresh');
    });

});
```