# Scrollspy with jQueryUI Accordion functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

So i've managed to figure out how to get scrollspy working, however I'm not realizing that my table of contents is too long for the navigation. I'm wondering how I can add an accordion type functionality so that my navbar table of contents will collapse after it has scrolled passed an associated anchor. I'm essentially looking for the same type of functionality that the bootstrap website has for it's affixed sidebar. I have looked at this: [Using bootstrap scrollspy for a div with collapse, to an affixed sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335507/using-bootstrap-scrollspy-for-a-div-with-collapse-to-an-affixed-sidebar/17339136#17339136)
but I'm not sure if thats the same thing I'm looking for. I've also considered using the TOCIFY plugin written by Greg Franko, but i'm not sure how to implement it. I've been reading the TOCIFY documentation but i'm not really sure what it is I have to change.

Currently my scrollspy functionality is working with this setup:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navbar" style="">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix">
            <li class="active h2-link"><a href="#executive-summary">Executive Summary</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#defining-mental-health">Defining Mental Health</a></li>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#review-process">Review Process</a></li>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#findings-and-recommendations">Findings and Recommendations</a></li>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#acknowledgement">Acknowledgement</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li class="h2-link"><a href="#preamble">Preamble</a></li>
            <li class="h2-link"><a href="#section-one">Section One: Our Context</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#MRU-world-of-difference">Mount Royal University: A World of Difference</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="h4-link"><a href="#MRU-vision">Mount Royal's Vision</a></li>
                        <li class="h4-link"><a href="#MRU-mission">Mount Royal's Mission</a></li>
                        <li class="h4-link"><a href="#MRU-guiding-principles">Mount Royal's Guiding Principles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#health-and-safety">Health and Safety at Mount Royal University</a></li>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#student-services-plan">Student Services Plan</a></li>
                <li class="h3-link"><a href="#rationale-for-student-mental-health">Rationale for a Student Mental Health Strategy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span9">

         <h2 id="executive-summary">Executive Summary</h2>
  </a>

  <h3 id="two">Introduction &amp; Background</h3>

  <p class="ParagraphText">Mount Royal University (MRU) has a long-standing history
  of student-centered leadership and learning.&nbsp;We are known to be an institution
  that cares about the success and the health of our students, and we have strong
  services that support mental health promotion and respond well to mental health
  issues and concerns. In addition to excellent service providers, MRU has many
  positive practices and policies in place to support students.&nbsp; Recent trends
  suggest that the prevalence of mental health issues is on the rise among young
  adults. More students are entering into university with pre-existing mental health
  conditions, more are seeking help, and often issues are complex and
  multifaceted.&nbsp; Given that rates of mental illness are on the rise, and given
  that our student population has reported stress levels higher than other students
  at post-secondary institutions in North American, a review of our student mental
  health practices and procedures was warranted.</p>
```

You can see it working here: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwvPQbnPrz_LTlBjelIwemxaZzg/index.html

I'd be grateful for any help or suggestions. I apologize if my research was not extensive enough and this has already been answered.

Comment: Tocify provides a demo page that you can download: https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.tocify.js/blob/master/demos/default.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it another go.