# How to collapse sub-elements of scrollspy when parent section is not active

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am trying to mimic how [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) scrollspy expands to show sub headers when the parent element is active, and how it continues to highlight those sub headers as you move through it. I have up to two sub headers.

I have the scrollspy working and highlighting each element as you scroll through the list. My problem is that I can't get the inner elements to hide when they're not active. I know I need to use Javascript or JQuery but I don't understand how.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168996/scrollspy-with-jqueryui-accordion-functionality) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335507/using-bootstrap-scrollspy-for-a-div-with-collapse-to-an-affixed-sidebar/17339136#17339136) but I don't think they're helpful enough for me.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').scrollspy({target: '#myScrollspy'})
    $('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function() {
        var ele = $(this).find('.active');
        if (ele.find('.children').length>0) {
          $('.children li').removeClass('hide');
        }
        else{
          $('.children li').addClass('hide');
        }
        $('body').scrollspy('refresh')
    });
    $('#myScrollspy ul li').on('click', function() {
      $('.children li').removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

Comment: I have added some javascript that almost does what I want, but it collapses every item that has sub elements when a section is scrolled over. Is there anyway to use $(this) to limit what is displayed?